# Can Microsoft PowerApps create public facing apps

Tags: powerapps

Is it possible to publish apps build with PowerApps for use by the general public i.e. people not in my organisation.

If so, do they scale well - to 10,000s of users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid, it is not possible at this time. There are resources that app needs that are currently only managed at tenant level.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, we just had a meeting with Microsoft about licensing & governing. It seems that every public user would also need to pay licensing fees. As such, I don't think this is meant to be used for the general public.

Comment: stating the obvious, don't need a meeting to know that.  How about changing their licensing and governing :)   its not like those public users will be using the PowerApp very often. And its not like it will add much load to their servers.   Sounds a but like when microsoft wanted everyone to pay for searching the internet.  look how that turned out.. rofl.

Answer (score 1):

Update for 2021

You can create a PowerApps Portal app (not canvas or model-driven) that allows external users to access it without signing in (public) and can be scaled to any need.

It's basically a website that you can pull data into using a Microsoft Dynamics 365 form.

It does require the data source to be Microsoft Dataverse (formerly Microsoft Common Data Service) and publicly available data.

Comment: Yes You are correct, there is a way to do this: https://powerapps.microsoft.com/it-ch/blog/powerapps-portals-is-now-available-for-public-preview/

The only problem is, that it is going to be a website, not an app.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

- Setting up an Azure instance with a kick ass domain name
- Develop PowerApps
- Spin off subdomains as needed for each "project"
- Sell per-user seats for each PowerApp

You'd have to bootstrap the distribution (no app store presence) somehow manage a ridiculous Azure AD and separately bill your customers but... its possible (notice I didn't use the word scalable) :P